# Traversing through rows of multiple dynamic tables at once using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am new to Jquery. I am learning the things one by one. my requirement is to create a dynamic jquery datatable.So I created in the following way:
The variable `formattedCKEY` is a dynamic value that I am using for generating the table id's dynamically

```
var issueTableId = "issuetable_"+formattedCKEY;
var $issuetable = $("
<table  id='" + issueTableId + "' class='stripe nowrap'  style='position:relative; top:0px; width:95%;'></table>
");
$issuetable.append('
<thead>
   ').children('thead')
   .append('
   <tr />
      ').children('tr')
      .append('
      <th nowrap>Select</th>
      '+
      '
      <th nowrap>Priority</th>
      ' +
      '
      <th nowrap>Issue ID</th>
      ' +
      var $tbody = $issuetable.append('
<tbody />
   ').children('tbody');
   $.each(cases, function () {
   $tbody.append('
   <tr />
      ').children('tr:last')
      .append('
      <td nowrap><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;</td>
      ')
      .append('
      <td nowrap>' + $(this).find("PRTY").text() + '</td>
      ')
      .append(sourceRow)
      .append('
      <td nowrap>' + $(this).find("ISSUEID").text() + '</td>
      ');
      });
```

Here I need to traverse through all the rows and verify if select box in checked in any row, if so get that row information. If the all the check boxes are selected in the dynamic table, I need to get all the row information.

I have tried with following code so far:

```
 //DataTables aplies style and behavior to <table>
 var table = $("#" + issueTableId).DataTable({
     "scrollY": 315, // inconsistent IE7/other
     "scrollX": true,
     "searching": false,
     "paging": false,
     "info": false
 });

 table.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop) {

 });
```

But somehow `table.rows().every()` is not working for me. My intention is to traverse through all the rows of the newly created dynamic table and verify the rows if they are selected.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please use each function of jQuery this will iterate each row.

```
$(".nowrap tr").each(function() {
       $(this).find('td').text() // find particular td value or text
       // check conditions

});
```